# How to find if one shape contains another shape

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have an array of shapes like this

```
$shapes = [
  [
    "BA",
    "AD",
    "DB"
  ],
  [
    "BC",
    "CD",
    "DA",
    "AB"
  ],
  [
    "BD",
    "DC",
    "CB"
  ]
]
```

They represents segments which are connected and form a shape.

[image]

However, you can see that I also have the larger shape which contains the 2 smaller shapes.
How can I get read of any shape that contains another shape?

We do have all coordinates x, y for all the vertices.

I am thinking to extract a list of vertices of all shapes and then the smaller ones should be present in the larger ones? Any other more efficient way?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the inner polygon's vertices are also vertices of the outer polygon?

Comment: Note you should probably use the word "polygon" rather than "shape" especially if you have been looking for an answer with a search engine

Comment: @Stef - all the polygons are gathered by an algorithm which is reading all possible polygons in a drawing. So some will be included in others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plausible solution:

1. break down the edges into a series of points and sort them into a priority queue. Given your example, it would be {A,B,D},{A,B,C,D},{B,C,D}. For easier reference, I call them alpha, beta, gamma respectively.
2. put the point chains into the final result one by one, if a shape in the result contains all the points of the new shape candidate, remove it. Let me put it in a flow graph:

result = {} --> result = {alpha} --> result = {alpha,beta} 
when adding gamma, we find that beta includes all points of gamma and has more points than gamma, so remove beta 
--> result = {alpha} --> result = {alpha,gamma}

This solution implies that each shape has a different set of points. If there are shapes share the same set of points, but are connected in different ways, you can modify this method by not using priority queue. Instead, put the points into a vector in the order how they are connected, and make sure the starting point of each shape is put in a certain order.

Let me know if you have further question